# Why List.fill method has two group of parameters instead of one?

Tags: scala

What is the reason behind List.fill is being defined with two groups of parameters instead of one with n and elem parameters together

Current definition

```
def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: ⇒ A): CC[A]
```

Proposed definition

```
def fill[A](n: Int, elem: ⇒ A): CC[A]
```

Isn't it unnecessary boilerplate? Or is it designed to use the first part (`List.fill(n)`) as a curried function constructor?

Comment: This allow to pass more easily a lambda block as `elem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
List.fill(10){ val r = math.random; r * r }
```

but you cannot write

```
List.fill(10, r = math.random; r * r)
```

and

```
List.fill(10, {r = math.random; r * r})
```

looks somewhat awkward.

In this case, it's almost irrelevant, but note that the way how the arguments are grouped into argument lists can influence the type inference quite significantly, e.g.

```
def map[X, Y](a: F[X])(f: X => Y): F[Y]
```

works perfectly fine without any type annotations most of the time, whereas

```
def map[X, Y](a: F[X], f: X => Y): F[Y]
```

is quite painful to use. Take a careful look at such methods as `ap`, `ap2` or `map2` [in this piece of code](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Apply.scala), for example. There is a good reason why the argument lists are the way they are, you would notice it immediately if they were defined differently.